# MVVMCross ValueConverter Parameter

Tags: mvvmcross, valueconverter

Hello MVVMCross community,

My question is about `ValueConverter`s parameters:

Is there any way to pass a variable to a Value Converter rather than a constant value as a `ConverterParameter`?

Something like:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrice"
    ...
    local:MvxBind="Text Price; Enabled IsPriceEnabled; BackgroundColor IsPriceEnabled, Converter=Enabled2MvxColor, ConverterParameter=Price"/>
```

or even pass the whole object for example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrice"
    ...
    local:MvxBind="Text Price; Enabled IsPriceEnabled; BackgroundColor IsPriceEnabled, Converter=Enabled2MvxColor, ConverterParameter=editPrice"/>
```

TIA,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Windows/XAML `IValueConverter` you can't really pass data-bound entries into the value converter parameter.

However, using the Tibet binding extensions within MvvmCross, you should be able to do this if you use the form:

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor Enabled2MvxColor(IsPriceEnabled, Price)"
```

For more on this - and on whole object binding, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar couple of days ago: it's rather convoluted:

```
<controls:OptionItemControl 
ItemTitle="{Binding Path=AccountSettings, Converter={StaticResource ContentItemConverter}, Mode=OneTime, 
ConverterParameter=DataRoaming.Text}"
ItemInfo="{Binding Path=AccountSettings, Converter={StaticResource ContentItemConverter}, Mode=OneTime, 
ConverterParameter=DataRoaming.Info}"
ItemValue="{Binding AccountSettings.DataRoaming, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

So my ViewModel has a property AccountSettings, which is a class that has another property DataRoaming, which has several properties like .Text, .Info

I am sure there is much easier way to do what I needed it to do, but I wanted to get from using magic string; I didn't get it at the end, but at-least this makes it easier for me to read and figure out.

so in converter I get the parameter, split it; then from value type and I can navigate through the properties and get the actual value from the class. Of course I could have as well called a method.

Hope this might give you some ideas.